# Topojson - Arcs for Singapore and Hong Kong

Tags: data-visualization, topojson

I noticed world-110m.json and world-110m2.json at https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/tree/master/examples didn't have the paths for Singapore and Hong Kong. I looked in the Natural Earth data set that generates the world-110m.json file, and noticed that Singapore was listed in the tiny_countries file, but only as a point, not as a polygon.  The normal countries file does not appear to include Singapore.  However, notice on  http://techslides.com/d3-world-maps-tooltips-zooming-and-queue/ that Singapore is not a point, but a path.

I notice that the above link has paths for Singapore and Hong Kong.  However, I'm having some problems using the files from that page because of some complicated code and would prefer to insert the arcs manually.

Thanks!

Comment: Still existing this issue here?

Comment: Yeah, still have no idea how to do this

Comment: this looks like a possible answer, from over on the GIS stackexchange https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/289336/26800

Comment: You can take a look at this issue https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/issues/76, it's about Datamap, but maybe you will be inspired

Answer (score 2):

ok, found a solution to this

1) get this specific admin-0 countries shapefile zip from natural earth `Admin - 0 Countries | Download countries` https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/

2) upload that 5mb `ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip` shapefile zip you downloaded from Natural Earth to https://mapshaper.org/

[image]

use the mouse to drag and the scroll wheel or the plus button to zoom and notice that both Hong Kong and Singapore exist as shapes/polygons in this shapefile:

#### Hong Kong

[image: Hong Kong]

#### Singapore

[image: Singapore]

3) in mapshaper, click `simplify` and then check `prevent shape removal` in the simplification menu that pops up

[image]

4) simplify your geography and then export it to topojson.  1% simplified is close to the `~500k` filesize of the original `world-110m2.json` file (edited)
the resulting "whole worth with shapes preserved for tiny countries" topojson files that I came up with are shared in this github reposititory https://github.com/micahstubbs/tiny-countries-geo/tree/master/out

[image: files]

Comment: datasource from this nice answer over on the gis stackexchange :-) https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/289336/26800